# Use arrows to navigate through element from textfields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to be able to use the keys (arrow down and arrow up) to navigate through the list that apears when typing in a textfield.

I got a list with names:

```
list: [
    { text: "Benny", id: 0 },
    { text: "Ben", id: 1 },
    { text: "Brianna", id: 2 }
  ]
```

I render the list like this:

```
var list = this.state.list.map((item, g) => {
  return (
    <ListItem key={item.id}>
      <Typography color="primary" variant="subtitle1">
        {item.text}
      </Typography>
    </ListItem>
  );
});
```

In the return function for the component I got a textfield inside a box and a ListMenu inside another box. The box with the ListMenu contains the ListItems rendered in the render. I want to be able just to use the keys to navigate through the list.

https://codesandbox.io/s/use-arrows-to-navigate-jw9uj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: I don't see any attempt to highlight anything in your reproduction. You describe what you want to create. But what is the actual problem you're facing when trying to do it?

Comment: Maybe you can try adding "keyup" event listener on text input box, then target event.keyCode for up and down arrows. In event listener callback target list and check if any selected then depending on on which up or down key, grab item from list and add class to it.

Comment: here you can see what I have tried. And the first elements get focused: https://codesandbox.io/s/use-arrows-to-navigate-jw9uj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark :-)

Comment: The Material-UI selection component [Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#autocomplete) fit your demand though, can't get a reason why you need Textfield